# Placeholders for apache2 VirtualHost

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

I have a conf like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/molfar/Sites/%-2+
</VirtualHost>
```

I'd like to dynamically set error and access logs paths. I tried the following

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    VirtualDocumentRoot /Users/molfar/Sites/%-2+
    ErrorLog "/private/var/log/apache2/%-2+_error.log"
    CustomLog "/private/var/log/apache2/%-2+_access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

But placeholders doesn't work in ErrorLog and CustomLog directives. Are there any other placeholders?

Answer (score 1):

No - the special substitutions that `VirtualDocumentRoot` uses are not available to other directives.  You can't split the files in this way if you're using `VirtualDocumentRoot`.

Instead, maybe modify your log format to include the requested host so that you're able to differentiate the requests to different host names?

Answer (score 1):

Checkout split-logfile - it is included in every Apache package.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/other.html